# How increase default x-axis length while data updated dynamically in highcharts

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

So when the data is added every second Highstocks start having a 'moving window'.

But can we set this moving window to something different than 5 seconds?

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-forked-kk8s0?file=/src/components/Chart.vue:0-852

Here is an example of the code

```
<template>
  <div>
    <highcharts
      :constructorType="'stockChart'"
      class="hc"
      :options="chartOptions"
      ref="chart"
    ></highcharts>
    
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      chartOptions: {
        rangeSelector: {
          selected: 0,
          
        },
        series: [
          {
            pointStart: Date.now(), // starting at the moment
            pointInterval: 1000 , // second data
            data: [1, 2, 3],
          },
        ],
      },
    };
  },
  created() {
    const that = this;

    var series = this.chartOptions.series[0];
    setInterval(function () {
      var x = new Date().getTime(), // current time
        y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
      series.data.push(Math.random() * 100);
    }, 1000);
  },
  methods: {
    
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean "5 seconds". The data is added every second and the chart moves every second. What is supposed to change that is (to you) 5 seconds long?

Comment: I mean: at any point of time five observations (5 seconds) are shown. What if I want that the limits of upper chart were wider? Let say 30 seconds.

Comment: As I can see on every change the axis extremes are set so there, for example, you can set a wider range. Or set eg min range by setting xAxis.minRange, API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.minRange